# LWCs that can work offline with JS library?

Tags: lightning-web-components, app-development, lwc-oss

Is there a way to have LWC components that can work offline on Salesforce mobile?

(The components in question will render diagrams etc).

So far I have only found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/04/how-to-pwa-offline-lwc).

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_fieldservice_242_mobile_lwc_overview.htm&type=5&release=242

Turns out it is available for FSL mobile app.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/offline_management.htm might be helpful if you're rolling your own app